# Find capitalized words in a text

Tags: python, cpu-word, capitalize

How to specify words that start with a capital letter and the number of that word in a text? If no word with this attribute is found in the text, print it in the None output. The words at the beginning of the sentence should not be considered. Numbers should not be considered and if the semicolon is at the end of the word, that semicolon should be omitted.

Like the following example:

Input:

```
The University of Edinburgh is a public research university in Edinburgh, Scotland. The University of Texas was included in the Association of American Universities in 1929.
```

Output:

```
2:University
4:Edinburgh
11:Edinburgh
12:Scotland
14:University
16:Texas
21:Association
23:American
24:Universities
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The words at the beginning of the sentence should not be considered

This makes the process harder because you should at first determine how the sentence is separated. a sentence can be ended with punctuation marks like `. or ! or ?`. But you did not close the last sentence in your example with a full stop. your corpus must be first preprocessed for this aim!

---

Putting this issue aside, suppose this scenario:

```py
import re

inp = "The University of Edinburgh is a public research university in Edinburgh, Scotland. The University of Texas was included in the Association of American Universities in 1929! The last Sentence."

sentences = re.findall(r"[\w\s,]*[\.\!\?]",inp)
counter = 0
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence = re.sub(r"\W", " ",sentence)
    sentence = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", sentence)
    words = re.split(r"\s", sentence)
    words = [w for w in words if w!=""]
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if word != "" and i != 0:
            if re.search(r"[A-Z]+", word):
                print("%d:%s" % (counter+i+1, word))
    counter += len(words)
```

This code is exactly what you want. It is not the best practice but it is a tight and simple code. Note that you need to specify the punctuations at the end of each sentence for the input sentence at first!!!

---

The output:

```
2:University                                                                                                                          
4:Edinburgh                                                                                                                           
11:Edinburgh                                                                                                                          
12:Scotland                                                                                                                           
14:University                                                                                                                         
16:Texas                                                                                                                              
21:Association                                                                                                                        
23:American                                                                                                                           
24:Universities                                                                                                                       
29:Sentence
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code was perfect.

Comment: @M_92 If it was helpful, please vote up my answer and tick it as an answer :)))))

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

It's just you have to use the `.istitle()` method on the string to check whether it starts with a capital letter and the rest of them are in lower case

And using regex, you can take out the word excluding the symbols at the end (assuming that you don't want to include symbols as you mentioned to ignore semicolon at the end of the word)

```py
import re

inp = 'The University; of Edinburgh is a public research university in Edinburgh, Scotland. The University of Texas was included in the Association of American Universities in 1929'
inp2 = ''

def capitalized_words_in_a_text(inp):
    lst = inp.split(' ')[1:]
    res = [f"{i}: {re.match(r'^[A-Za-z]+', j).group()}" for i,j in enumerate(lst, start=2) if j.istitle()]

    if len(res) == 0:
        return
    return '\n'.join(res)

print(capitalized_words_in_a_text(inp))
print(capitalized_words_in_a_text(inp.lower()))
```

Outputs:

```
2: University
4: Edinburgh
11: Edinburgh
12: Scotland
13: The
14: University
16: Texas
21: Association
23: American
24: Universities
None # this is from the inp.lower() line, as there's no capital letters in the string
```

Tell me if its not working...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code. You can add any other character to strip and it should remove it from the end of the word. You can also change the last print to anything you want.

```
import numpy as np

s1="The University of Edinburgh is a public research university in Edinburgh, Scotland. The University of Texas was included in the Association of American Universities in 1929."

n = []

for index, word in enumerate(s1.split()):
    if word[0].isupper():
        if string[index-1][-1] == ".": #check that previous word does not end in a ".". 
            continue
        print(f"""{index+1}:{word.strip(",.;:")}""") #python index is one number lower, so add one to it to get the numbers you requested
        n.append(word) #this is just to be able to print something if no words have capital letters
if len(n) == 0:
    print("None")
```